# Linux Mint Cinnamon HiDPI scaled with xrandr -- laggy interface?

Tags: display, nvidia-graphics-card, cinnamon, high-dpi, xrandr

I am running Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.

I have two 4K monitors running their native display.
Everything is too small for me.

Then I turn on HiDPI scaling in the Cinnamon settings under General.
This makes everything too big, but it is very crisp.

So then I run this xrandr command:

`xrandr --output DP-0 --scale 1.25x1.25 --output DP-2 --scale 1.25x1.25 --pos 4800x0`

This looks beautiful and is the right size. However, the user interface is noticably laggy. Dragging windows for example is not as smooth as it is before the xrandr scaling.

Is this expected behavior? Is it to be expected that xrandr scaling will reduce performance? I have a powerful graphics card on this machine (NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL [Quadro P400]), so I am a bit surprised.

Are there other workarounds to getting what I want (crisp, HiDPI, with the actual resolution somewhere between the native and 1/2 that)?

I have tried not turning on Cinnamon HiDPI scaling and just using xrandr scale with a factor of .75. This makes things very blurry though.